# How can an <img> scale to the height of a sibling?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The title is pretty self-descriptive. Just keep in mind that the container element is supposed to have its own width and height, as shown on the example. While this example is written in flexbox, I don't mind using other methods as long as it's pure, clean HTML/CSS.

I feel like this should be trivial, but I've been looking for a while, including related answers on Stack Overflow, and I can't seem to find any satisfactory answer.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <h2>Dolor Sit Amet, here's some extra text</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a few more divs, this is possible.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h2>Dolor Sit Amet, here's some extra text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm tempted to say this one is a correct solution, *but* [notice how the `<img>` overflows from the wrapper](https://i.imgur.com/CmeMFkA.png)

Comment: @Xerz hmm... try adding flex-shrink: 0 to .img-wrap?

Comment: Seems to have no effect... I wouldn't mind as much if I didn't want to center the content or align it to the right, honestly

Comment: @Xerz Looks like it's only really an issue in Firefox, in Chrome it works as expected. I messed around with it a bit but for some reason Firefox just isn't expanding the parent container when the image inside it grows. I'm not certain, but I want to say it's a bug/oversight on their part.

Comment: Oh right, it seems to be Firefox-specific behavior. Perhaps I should open a ticket in Bugzilla or WebCompat.

Comment: Opened a ticket at https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/38951, in the mean time I'll accept this answer. Thanks a lot! 

Comment: This solution will only scale the image up, if needed, but will not scale it down.

Answer (score 2):

If like me you have an image that could be longer than the sibling element, the following worked for me

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

/* Some extra styling */
.sibling {
  border: 1px dotted #999;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sibling">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h2>Dolor Sit Amet, here's some extra text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place the two siblings into a parent `<div>`, give the parent tag a set height, and then give the `<img/>` tag a height of 100%. This way it will scale to the height of the parent box.
For example,

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <h2>Dolor Sit Amet, here's some extra text</h2>
  </div>
  <img style="height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: I don't want to have a fixed height though, I want to set it dynamically to match the sibling `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Properly Structuring the image into div and applying `flex` property should do the trick.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <h2>Dolor Sit Amet, here's some extra text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap flex-1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
  }

  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
.flex-1{
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like this answer does anything to fix the overflow issue, otherwise it's the same as Matt's

Comment: flex: 1 should not allow the image to overflow. Can you please share a pen if it does overflow

Comment: Oh, that explains why things look perfect in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the `height: 100vh` from the parent (`body`) and set `align-self` to `stretch` on the image. However that won’t preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

A better approach is to use grid:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  grid-row: 2;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h2>Dolor Sit Amet, here's some extra text</h2>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64" />
</body>

</html>
```